# Scrapy for trying to comple a login form at freelancer

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to log in to a website [login](https://www.freelancer.es/login) using Scrapy and then become inside at [main](https://www.freelancer.es/dashboard/). I have successfully done this for other websites but I'm not sure why this time does not working.

I'm using this spider.

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'free'
    allowed_domains=["freelancer.es"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.freelancer.es/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname = 'LoginForm',
            formdata = {'username': 'username', 'password': 
                'password'}, 
            callback=self.after_login
    )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        x = response.xpath('//html/title/text()')
        print x
```

After that, if I want to add some code lines at my 'after_login' function, doesn't write that I expected. This page haven't a csrf token then, the formdata obtain just user and password.

This is a partial image of my [command prompt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fGX3PyMcOk8HcydRbo6cYWAaow7fOh_r).

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what is _"not working"_? Does running your code display or return some error(s)?

Comment: If my actual spider be working, i can get acces to 'https://www.freelancer.es/dashboard/' and scrape this site, actually my acount, but that does not hapend. I'm back to the login page, it's as if nothing had happened.

Comment: Try to use `formname` instead of `formid` because there is no `id` attribute for the target form